# react-native-print print of documents with data set in react native using html

Tags: react-native, printing

Is there any way to display my data set into the html within **async printHTML()**  I am using react native. Hope anyone can help me, It would be gladly appreciated, I've been working on it for how many hours. Thank you!

I tried using this way but it is not working, i just diaplay **{dataSet1 ? dataSet1.map((dataSet1 , index) => ({dataSet1 .name} ))  : No data}** as a text

```
async printHTML() {
  await RNPrint.print({
    html: '<h1>Heading 1</h1>{dataSet1 ? dataSet1.map((dataSet1 , index) => (<div>{dataSet1 .name}</div> ))  : <div>No data</div>}'
  })
}
```

this is the dataset i want to display

```
 const dataSet1 = [
      {
          name: "Johson",
          amount: 30000,
          sex: 'M',
          is_married: true
      },
      {
          name: "Monika",
          amount: 355000,
          sex: 'F',
          is_married: false
      },
      {
          name: "John",
          amount: 250000,
          sex: 'M',
          is_married: false
      },
      {
          name: "Josef",
          amount: 450500,
          sex: 'M',
          is_married: true
      }
    ];
```

Here is my Function

```
async printHTML() {
  await RNPrint.print({
    html: `<h1>Custom converted PDF Document</h1>
    <h1>Custom converted PDF Document</h1>
    <h1>Custom converted PDF Document</h1>
    <h1>Custom converted PDF Document</h1>
    `,
  })
}
```

Andt this is my render component

```
render(){
   return(
    <Container style={{backgroundColor: '#f4f5f9'}}>
        <View>
        <View style={styles.container}>  
        <Button onPress={this.printHTML} title="Print HTML" />
      </View>
      </View>
  </Container>
   )
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

insert my data in an state

```
this.state = {   
      loading: false,
      sound: 'off',
      selectedPrinter: null,
      dataSet1: [
        {
            name: "Johson",
            amount: 30000,
            sex: 'M',
            is_married: true
        },
        {
            name: "Monika",
            amount: 355000,
            sex: 'F',
            is_married: false
        },
        {
            name: "John",
            amount: 250000,
            sex: 'M',
            is_married: false
        },
        {
            name: "Josef",
            amount: 450500,
            sex: 'M',
            is_married: true
        }
      ]
    }
```

Get the data to be displayed in table

```
renderTableData(){
  return this.state.dataSet1.map((dataSet1, index) => {
    const { name, amount, sex } = dataSet1
    return (
      `<tr key=${index}>
        <td>${name}</td>
        <td>${amount}</td>
        <td>${sex}</td>
      </tr>`
    )
  })
}
```

Call the function here

```
async printHTML() {
  let html_content = 
  `<h1>Hello, UppLabs!</h1>
<table>
<tbody>

${this.renderTableData()}
</tbody>
</table>`
  await RNPrint.print({
    html : html_content  })
}
```

change the button on press

```
 render(){

   return(
    <Container style={{backgroundColor: '#f4f5f9'}}>
    
        <View>
        
        <Button onPress={() => {this.printHTML()}} title="Print HTML" />
   
      
      </View>
      
      </View>
  </Container>
   )
 }
```